# Creating a search bar with Django to query a MongoDB database

Tags: django, mongodb

I have a search bar where I want to search for perfumes in a MongoDB database. I tried two ways but it never works.

Here is the HTML template for both:

`search_similar.html`:

```html
{% extends "todo/base.html" %}
 {% block content %}
  <div class="recommendations">
    <!-- <div class="login-page"> -->
      <div class="form">
        <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
          <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
          <input type ="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" />
        </form>
        <form class="login-form" action = "/predict" method="POST">
          <input type="text" placeholder="perfume name"/> <!-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRODv6UTXpM&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge -->
          <input type ="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" />
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

`views.py`:

```
import pymongo
import todo.config as config
from django.db.models import Q


username = config.username
password = config.password

...

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        perfume_list = list(collection.find({'q0.Results.0.Name': {"$regex" : query}}, {'item_name': 1, 'brand': 1, 'gender': 1,
                                                                         'note': 1, 'tags': 1, 'theme': 1, '_id': 0}))

        print("perfume_list: ", perfume_list)
        return perfume_list
```

But `perfume_list` is hopelessly empty.

But even in MongoDB Atlas, I have problems to search in nested dictionaries. Indeed the query in the image below does not give the result that we can see:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Anexo: `urls.py`

`urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo import views

urlpatterns = [

    ...

    # similar
    path('similar', views.search_similar, name='similar'),
    path('similar_results', views.SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results')

]
```

Comment: Don't know about your query (never used pymongo) but one problem you have is your url patterns need to end in a trailing slash. `path('similar/', ...)` and `path('similar_results/', ...)`. Django appends slashes to any url that doesn't have them and redirects the user causing any form data to be lost. You can change this by setting `APPEND_SLASH = False` (not recommended just end urls in slashes).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AbdulAzizBarkat. I added the / but it seems that I lose the CSS in that process. I don't get the data retrieved either...

Comment: For the CSS, since I added the / I have the following error in the debug console : `Not Found: /similar/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js`. This bootstrap component is held in the html files that is extended for `todo/find_similar.html`: `todo/base.html`. Do you know how

Comment: It appears you write your static urls manually like `href="static/..."` firstly when you write relative urls start them with a leading slash so `href="/static/..."`. When a relative url starts with a leading slash it means it is from the domain, if it doesn't have a leading slash it is from the current page. Secondly don't write static urls directly instead first at start of your template write `{% load static %}` then write `href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/...' %}"`